# Execute javascript function in code behind (c#) multiple times

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have an datatable and for each row i need  execute a javascript function (same javascript function, but with diferent values).

For each row, it executed a javascript function and it is returned the result to the code behind (trought web method).

But, with my actual code the function it only execute one time (first row of table).

I have this:
c#

```
 string strScript = "";
foreach (DataRow row in dtLodgings.Rows)
{
    strScript = strScript + "\n" + "GetInfoGMaps('" + row["Name"].ToString() + "'," + row["Latitude"].ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "," + row["Longitude"].ToString().Replace(",", ".")+ ");";
}
  strScript = strScript.Replace("'", "\'");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "GetInfoGMaps", strScript, true);
```

javascript

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
var map, service;
function GetInfoGMaps(name, latitude, longitude) {
    var loc= null;
    if (latitude != "" && longitude != "") {
        loc  = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: loc,
        zoom: 15
    });

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    var request = {location: loc, radius: 50000, keyword: name};

    service.radarSearch(request, callback); // i got the data and i sent to c# trought ajax
}
```

c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GetInfoGMaps(InfoMaps lodg)
{
   if (lodg != null)
   {
      // the data is saved in database
   }
}
```

I tried to execute the strString in console (chrome web browser), but I getand *undefined* and I don't understand why. It seems that when I run radarSearch function gives undefined.

```
GetInfoGMaps('Mak Albania Resort Durres',41.2314605712891,19.5132293701172);
GetInfoGMaps('Mak Albania Resort Durres',41.2314605712891,19.5132293701172);
GetInfoGMaps('Mak Albania Resort Durres',41.2314605712891,19.5132293701172);
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: you want one map or multiple maps?

Comment: one map only. the objective is to access the details of some places.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx), each startup script is uniquely identified by its key and its type. Scripts with the same key and type are considered as duplicates. Add unique values to each key like this..

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows) {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "GetInfoGMaps" + i, "GetInfoGMaps('" + row["Name"].ToString() + "'," + row["Latitude"].ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "," + row["Longitude"].ToString().Replace(",", ".")");", true);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It is the same. Only the last line is executed.

Comment: check if there is any problem with your `GetInfoGMaps` method.. May be each iteration is overwriting the previous one.

Comment: I updated my code. I used console.log and I think that my error is in radarSearch function, but i dont understand why.

Answer (score 0):

- ClientScript should be outside foreach loop, since you register  **GetInfoGMaps** N rows times.
- foreach to create your script string first.

  - clean/escape `'` char to avoid breaking your javascript
- it will give another benefit : you can breakpoint your script string before sending client.

Example :

```
string strScript = "";

foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows) {
   strScript = strScript + "\n" +  "GetInfoGMaps('" + row["Name"].ToString() + "'," + row["Latitude"].ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "," + row["Longitude"].ToString().Replace(",", ".")");";

}
//clean/escape ' char to avoid breaking your script
clientScript = clientScript.Replace("'", "\'")

// now it may be ok :
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "GetInfoGMaps", clientScript, true);
```

### Can't check my code on visual studio (on my Mac right now), so it may contain errors but idea is here.

Comment: It is the same. The strString  appears with the correct number of iterations, but performs only the last row.

Example of my strString:
GetInfoGMaps ('Lido Hotel Durres' 41.322681427002,19.4581604003906,25);
GetInfoGMaps ('Hotel Apollonia Durres' 41.3135414123535,19.4765796661377,33);
GetInfoGMaps ('Mak Albania Resort Durres' 41.2314605712891,19.5132293701172,56);

Comment: Hard to see so. I would console.log my javascript to try to debut why it does not work like wanted.

Comment: I had a try with your script but I encounter an error : `can't find lodging_name`. I don't see  yours but I used this service :`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, my mistakes. I updated my code, but yes, it is the Google Places  script.